# Adding query referencing another table in main and sub-selects

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table for showing target and completion times and all of the information is from one table "job" - however I now want to add some more SQL in to provide some information from another table "job_type" but whenever I keep getting error messages saying 
"SQLSTATE = S0022  [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00904: "JOB_TYPE"."JOB_TYPE_CODE": invalid identifier.

The code I have that works (without the bit I want adding is)

```
select 
job_number, priority_code, job_entry_date, clock_start, 
site_code,
TO_CHAR(job_entry_date, 'Dy') as DAY_LOGGED,
TO_CHAR(actual_start_date, 'IW') as WEEK_ON_SITE,
actual_start_date,
actual_comp_date,

-- kpi tracker
CASE
WHEN actual_start_date is null AND current_date < target_time THEN 'Not arrived on site yet'
WHEN actual_start_date is null AND current_date > target_time THEN 'FAIL (2)'
when actual_start_date <= target_time then 'Pass'
when actual_start_date > target_time then 'FAIL'
ELSE 'Overdue' END as Arrived_on_time_check,

-- start of correct target time SQL
case
when to_char(target_time, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Fri'
and floor((target_time - trunc(target_time)) * 24) >= 17
then target_time + 2 + 63/24
when floor((target_time - trunc(target_time)) * 24) >= 17
then target_time + 15/24
else target_time
end as target_time

from 
        (
        select job_number, priority_code, job_entry_date, clock_start, site_code, actual_start_date, actual_comp_date, 
        CASE 
        WHEN PRIORITY_CODE IN ('GC01','GC02','GC03','GC04','GC05','GC06','GC07') 
        THEN
        clock_start + case priority_code 
        when 'GC01' then 1 
        when 'GC02' then 2 
        when 'GC03' then 0.5
        when 'GC04' then 1 
        when 'GC05' then 2 
        when 'GC06' then 4
        when 'GC07' then 24
        end / 24 
        ELSE TARGET_COMP_DATE END as target_time

        from                
                    (
                    select job_number, priority_code, job_entry_date, target_comp_date, site_code, actual_start_date, actual_comp_date,
                    case
                    when to_char(job_entry_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Fri'
                    and floor((job_entry_date - trunc(job_entry_date)) * 24) >= 17
                    then trunc(job_entry_date) + 80/24
                    when to_char(job_entry_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Sat'
                    then trunc(job_entry_date) + 56/24
                    when to_char(job_entry_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Sun'
                    or floor((job_entry_date - trunc(job_entry_date)) * 24) >= 17
                    then trunc(job_entry_date) + 32/24
                    when floor((job_entry_date - trunc(job_entry_date)) * 24) < 8
                    then trunc(job_entry_date) + 8/24
                    else job_entry_date
                    end as clock_start
                    from job
                    )

        )




where
priority_code in ('GC01','GC02','GC03','GC04','GC05','GC06','GC07')
```

The code I want to add in is:

```
-- JOB KPI ATTRIBUTE LOOK UP IN GJOB TABLE
(SELECT attribute_value.attrib_value_name FROM attribute_value WHERE 
attribute_value.attrib_type_code = 'GJOB' 
AND attribute_value.attrib_value_code = job_type.job_type_code) as JOB_KPI,

-- JOB KPI PENALTY POINTS LOOK UP IN GJOB TABLE
(SELECT attribute_value.attrib_value_nom FROM attribute_value WHERE 
attribute_value.attrib_type_code = 'GJOB' 
AND attribute_value.attrib_value_code = job_type.job_type_code) as KPI_POINTS,
```

How do I add in the above code to the existing code without the error messages saying that it's an invalid identifier?

Comment: I don't see the job_type table in any of your FROM statements?